# Finding the shortest distance between two nodes given multiple graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, graph-traversal

Assume that we have a set of nodes and multiple graphs with different edge values for the same set of nodes. As an example, there are 4 nodes `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. And we have 3 graphs named `GRAPH_1`, `GRAPH_2` and `GRAPH_3` as shown in the figure below.

[image: Input Graphs]

From using any number of graphs I need to find the shortest path between two nodes. If I want to move from `A` to `D`, then, first I can move from `A` to `B` using `GRAPH_1`, next move from `B` to `C` using `GRAPH_3` and finally move from `C` to `D` using `GRAPH_2`.

[image: Expected Answer]

So the answer we need is like `(A->B: G1, B->C: G3, C->D: G2)`.

How can I do this optimally?

Note: The nodes are exactly same in all given graphs, but the edges can be different. And also we can use any number of nodes or edges.

Comment: @Juho We need to find the shortest weighted path. In the example if we use only `GRAPH_1` then the minimum weight will be 7 ( A->B->C). But in the answer we got 6  as shown above (2 + 1 + 3).

Comment: So what if you build a new graph, and put in each edge (if any) with the lowest weight and run Dijkstra on that?

Comment: @Juho yes, but the problem is in the answer we also need the graphs we have used in the order. The answer will be like (A->B: G1, B->C: G3, C->D: G2)

Comment: You should specify this constraint in the question, or at least I don't see it. Can you please edit it to make it clear?

Comment: What do you mean by "graphs we have used in the order"? Couldn't you just keep track of which graph the edge came from? (Also, are these edges unique?)

Comment: "How can I do this optimally?" Are you looking for a solution that is provably optimal? The best solution will probably be merging graphs and running Dijkstra, but proving this is optimal might be difficult.

Comment: @Juno Exactly what we need is just keeping track of which graph the edge came from.